# jquery: how to ignore immediate children() and go deeper until match specified element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(this).parent().parent()
.children(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase())
.css("background-color", "yellow");
```

xpath:

```
/html/body/div/table/tr/td/b/a
```

`$(this).tagName` is Anchor `<a>`

the problem with this is that children() looks at the immediate children of `$(this).parent().parent()`. Hence it will highlight `<b>` instead of `<a>`

i need a way to ignore this immediate children restriction, and select `<a>` not `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`find()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find) to search all descendants:

```
$(this).parent().parent()
.find(this.attr("tagName").toLowerCase())
.css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Unless you are trying to highlight all  tags at the same level as "this" in which case try:

```
$(this).siblings("a").css("background-color", "yellow");
```